# On clone date picker is not working in jquery

Tags: jquery

This is my code and datepicker is not working in it.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  var html = '<div id="element3"><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-3"><label for="exampleSelect1" class="bmd-label-floating">Providers</label><select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="carprovider[]"><option value="">--Select Type--</option><option value="1">1</option></select></div></div><input type="hidden" name="id"><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-3"><label for="exampleTextarea" class="bmd-label-floating">Pick Up Date</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-22" name="pickupdate[]"></div></div><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-3"><label for="exampleTextarea" class="bmd-label-floating">Pick Up Time</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-23" name="pickuptime[]"></div></div><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-3"><label for="exampleTextarea" class="bmd-label-floating">Drop Date</label><input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-24" name="dropdate[]"></div></div><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-2"><label for="exampleTextarea" class="bmd-label-floating">Drop Time</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="droptime[]"> </div></div><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-2"><label for="exampleTextarea" class="bmd-label-floating">Car Hire Type</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="carhiretype[]"></div></div><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-2"><label for="exampleTextarea" class="bmd-label-floating">Ref No.</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="refno[]"></div></div><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-2"><label for="exampleSelect1" class="bmd-label-floating">Currency</label><select class="form-control" id="exampleSelect1" name="currency[]"><option>--Select Type--</option><option value="gb">GB</option></select></div></div><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-2"><label for="exampleTextarea" class="bmd-label-floating">B. Price</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="bprice[]"></div></div><div class="form-row"><div class="form-group col-md-2"><label for="exampleTextarea" class="bmd-label-floating">Price</label><input type="text" class="form-control" name="price[]"></div></div><button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" id="cancel14">Cancel</button></div>';

  var max = 5;
  var x = 1;
  $("#add14").click(function() {
    if (x <= max) {
      $("#element3").append(html);
      x++;
    }
  });

  $("#element3").on('click', '#cancel14', function() {
    $(this).closest('div').remove();
    x--;
  });
});
```

Comment: You need to instantiate the datepickers. Assuming this uses jQuery UI, just call `.datepicker()` on them after appending the new HTML. There's a couple of other things though, firstly the PHP tag is irrelevant to this question so I've removed it. Secondly, there's no cloning here, you're just appending new content. Lastly, that's *far* too much HTML to be placed in your JS logic. Look in to using templating.

Comment: Your Cancel button should be removing the div that you inserted using `#add14`... Could you please add a question so we can help...

Comment: I tested your code and it works fine... why are you expecting this: `<input type="text" class="form-control" id="datepicker-22" name="pickupdate[]">` to be a date picker? are you using a plugin or something else?